# add and remove operation with gitdb

Tags: python, git, github

I have a project and I have to use gitdb with python. When I search on google I just find [gitdb Documents](https://gitdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). And it doesn't have any basic example. I found just that code snipped which I don't understand about it clearly.

```
#/usr/bin/python
import os,sys,zlib,gitdb
from gitdb.db import LooseObjectDB
from gitdb.pack import PackEntity
from gitdb.util import bin_to_hex,hex_to_bin

ldb=LooseObjectDB(sys.argv[1]+'/.git/objects')
PackEntity.create((ldb.stream(sha) for sha in ldb.sha_iter()),sys.argv[1]+'/.git/objects/pack',object_count=ldb.size(),zlib_compression=zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)
```

Could anybody have any recommendation for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* you have to to use `gitdb`? The `gitdb` module is a low-level module for interacting with the Git repository structure.  It is used by [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython), which is a higher-level interface to Git repositories.

I imagine you can either use GitPython -- which is [well documented with lots of examples](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) -- in your project, or you can at least use it as a reference to see how one uses the `gitdb` module.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I ask my project manager your advice.

Comment: You right. My project manager talked to me like your advice. Thank you again :):)